# Does @@IDENTITY in an SP using triggers result in a race condition?

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, triggers, identity

If I were to use `@@IDENTITY` in a SQL sp which also activated a trigger, would it result in a race condition?

Say I perform an `INSERT INTO TABLE_A` which triggers an `INSERT INTO TABLE_B` then, in the current scope I use `@@IDENTITY`

Would I **always** get the resulting identity from the trigger (`TABLE_B`) or would it depend on which thread finished first?

Note: I know about `SCOPE_IDENTITY`, this question is hypothetical....

Comment: The trigger executes, by definition, after the insert. I don't think they can be reasonably threaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you'll always get the identity from table B, because your transaction in Table A isn't considered complete and committed (and your T-SQL isn't allowed to advance) until the insert and trigger are both complete. Even if you're using an AFTER trigger, you're still waiting until the trigger code is done before you get to the next line and ask for the @@identity.